# Cannot invoke 'sendAsynchronousRequest' in Swift 2 with an argument list

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm currently rewriting parts of my Swift 1.2 code for compatibility with Swift 2.0. Actually I cannot figure out what changes are made to "sendAsynchronousRequest" - currently all my requests fail

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in})
```

> Cannot invoke 'sendAsynchronousRequest' with an argument list of type
>   '(NSURLRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue, completionHandler:
>   (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Do you have any Idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3, the signature of `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is:

```
class func sendAsynchronousRequest(request: NSURLRequest,
    queue: NSOperationQueue!,
    completionHandler handler: (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)
```

With Swift 2 and Xcode 7 beta, however, the signature of `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` has changed and is now:

```
// Note the non optionals, optionals and implicitly unwrapped optionals differences
class func sendAsynchronousRequest(request: NSURLRequest,
    queue: NSOperationQueue,
    completionHandler handler: (NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void)
```

As a consequence, turning to Swift 2 and Xcode 7 beta, you will have to change your `completionHandler` parameter implementation and ensure that your `queue` parameter is a non optional.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the problem is with your implicit unwrapped optionals in the completion block. Just make it optional and it should work fine,

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
  let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
  print("Response \(string!)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` is deprecated in iOS 9. Should use `NSURLSession` `public func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask`

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
    let url:URL? = URL(string:location)
    if url == nil {
        print("malformed url : \(location)")
    }

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(URLRequest(url:url!),
        queue: OperationQueue.main)
    { (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in

    }
```