# sendAsynchronousRequest deprecated in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to change my code from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0 but I'm having some problems regarding the "sendAsynchronousRequest" because it's always showing a warning because it's deprecated. I have tried using another solution from this post: [Cannot invoke 'sendAsynchronousRequest' in Swift 2 with an argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774623/cannot-invoke-sendasynchronousrequest-in-swift-2-with-an-argument-list) but it's still not working and I'm having the same warning again.

What I have to change in my code to solve this warning? The warning is the following:

*sendAsynchronousRequest was deprecated in iOS 9, use dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler*

**This is my code:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // try to reuse cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MarcaCollectionViewCell

    // get the deal image
    let currentImage = marcas[indexPath.row].imagen
    let unwrappedImage = currentImage
    var image = self.imageCache[unwrappedImage]
    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: marcas[indexPath.row].imagen)

    // reset reused cell image to placeholder
    cell.marcaImageView.image = UIImage(named: "")

    // async image
    if image == nil {

        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?,data: NSData?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                image = UIImage(data: data!)

                self.imageCache[unwrappedImage] = image
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    cell.marcaImageView.image = image

                })
            }
            else {

            }
        })
    }

    else {
        cell.marcaImageView.image = image
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: So you want to suppress the warning or you want to move to `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler` ?

Comment: Hi @Wain, I would like to make it right, so I prefer to suppress the warning if that's correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppressing the warning for deprecated methods is not a good idea. Just move to using NSURLSession as the warning advises you.

Comment: Correct mean upgrading to the new API as the deprecated API is now out of date and will be unsupported and removed in the future

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Abizern, could you please guide me a little bit to change the code to a NSURLSession? Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to write your code for you.  Read the documentation, try it for yourself, and ask a specific question if you still have problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the warning warns, NSURLConnection is dead. Long live NSURLSession.

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let urlString = "https://api.yoursecureapiservergoeshere.com/1/whatever"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
  print("done, error: \(error)")
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick example @Keller, I have change some things from your code and now it's working without warning. Much appreciated.

Comment: can you please tell me keller how can i pushviewcontroller  with passing a dictionary after getting the response of webservice?

Comment: either add a dictionary argument to your view controller's initializer or if you're using storyboard segues, keep the dictionary in a property and set it in prepareForSegue. you should also ensure you push the view controller on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSURLSession` instead like below,

For Objective-C

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"YOUR URL"]
          completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                              NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSError *error) {
            // handle response

  }] resume];
```

For Swift,

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "YOUR URL"))
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var params = ["username":"username", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")})

task.resume()
```